# Getting error "you are about to view pages over a secure connection" in IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, iis-6

My website is hosted in more than one server. Client requests are handled through F5 loader, and passed to one of the server in round robin manner. Currently, I've detached one of the server for some testing. The websites are using https protocol. Once a request crosses from F5, the https request is converted into http request.

When I'm trying to access the website hosted in the detached server with the IP configured in IIS. I'm getting the below error:

> *You are about to view pages over a secure connection. Any information you exchange with this site cannot be viewed by anyone else on the
>   web*

I'm passing http url with IP (and not the DNS name) in the IE browser, but when the response is coming, it is in https. Not able to understand how the http request is getting converted again into https, or why the error is coming.

Please let me know, if any extra information is required.

Comment: check this link [You are about to view pages over a secure connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012776)

Comment: Thanks Soner. But I just checked, the same error is coming in other browser as well. I checked in Chrome.